# webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch Unknown property name

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, webkit

I encounter this problem when trying to create a popover (using bootstrap modal) with overflow-y:scroll for a website targeting **mobile devices**. The problem is when I try to scroll the element inside the popover, *the background is also scrolled*.

I notice that the CSS does not recognize this property, as in this message:

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch (Unknown property name.)
```

Does anyone know the cause of this? And is there any possible fix or work-around?

Comment: -webkit-overflow-scrolling will only work on your device & the background scrolling sounds like a separate issue. Maybe you should get a fiddle going.

Comment: Perhaps you are referring to the "Overflow and scrolling" issue mentioned in http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-fixed-position-keyboards ?

Comment: "trying to create a popover (using bootstrap modal)" Bootstrap has its own separate popover widget, so your phrasing is somewhat confusing.